# Using the ActiveAdmin Submit button in relation to attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, attr-accessible

I'm currently changing around how my ActiveAdmin interface works so that it integrates both `attr_accessible` items and CanCan.  In some of my models I have a specific controller action for the Submit button on the form such as

```
= f.actions do
= f.action :submit, label: 'Update Password'
```

And in that `Update Password` method I am able to do the `update_attributes(*,as: @admin_user.role.name.to_sym)` where `@admin_user` is the current admin user.  This allows only admin users with the permitted role to update their password.

The problem I have is when ActiveAdmin is doing the generic update, specifically

```
=f.action :submit
```

How can I pass options to ActiveAdmin so that when it does the update it will use the specified role?  I know that the buttons use Formtasti, and that the `:label` method is part of that, but I can't seem to find anything about using passing other options.

One option for me is to write an override for the edit method in each of my models, but that kinda defeats the purpose of ActiveAdmin, doesn't it?

Now, my CanCan abilities already have been set so that only certain roles can access certain items.  Does this override the `attr_accessible` items?  I know that if the item is *not* `attr_accessible`, even if it's manageable in CanCan, will not change via mass-assignment.

What I really need to know is that if I were a hacker, could I inject an `update_attributes(params[:whatever], as: :admin)` and it would block it because of CanCan's Ability?  Is it worth it to have both the item be protected via `attr_accessible`and CanCan's Ability class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveAdmin and SimpleForm do not support the `as: [role]` feature which I was trying to work with.  However, this isn't a problem with strong_parameters in Rails 4 since it's a completely different way of handling mass-assignment.

Also, CanCan does block out any mass-assignment hacks since you can't mass-assign unless you have access to the form, and if you don't have explicit `:edit, :update, or :manage` permission then you don't have access to the form.